# Bilinear form and linear functionals

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, normed-spaces

Given any two Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$ over the same field $F$ (=$\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), let $X^*$ and $Y^*$ denote the topological dual of $X$ and $Y$, respectively. Denote the collection of all Bilinear forms on $X\times Y$ by $B(X\times Y, F)$. Obviously, bounded Bilinear forms are continuous. Note that we do not have any norm structure on $X\times Y$. However, it is known that $X\times Y$ is metrizable.

Now, consider the topology on $X\times Y$ induced by the family $B(X\times Y, F)$. Is this topology Hausdorff? What is its relation with the topology induced on $X\times Y$ by the family $X^*\times Y^*$?

A detailed answer would be of very much help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We *do* have a norm on $X \times Y$ that is complete and compatible with the product topology...

Comment: yes and that is why I do not want to impose any particular norm on $X\times Y$ fortiori@HennoBrandsma

Comment: $X^\ast \times Y^\ast$ "works" on $X \times Y$ by $(f,g)$ giving rise to a map $(x,y) \to f(x)g(y)$ ? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I meant the topology induced on $X\times Y$ by the family of all bilinear forms on $X\times Y$.

Comment: I meant what is the topology induced by $X^* \times Y^*$?

Comment: Apologies for misunderstanding.  I meant exactly the same thing you have mentioned! $X^*\times Y^*$ "works" ....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128479/discussion-between-pmun-and-henno-brandsma).